# save array values on reload and retrieve it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am pushing some random values into an array every minute.

On reloading I want to retrieve back this pushed content and keep pushing some random data every minute?

I am using local storage.

**MyCODE--:**

```
localStorage.setItem("test",Myarray.push(JSON.stringify(data)));
var test2 = localStorage.getItem("test");
test = JSON.parse(test2); //var test is now re-loaded!
console.log(test);
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push the data to the array, then store it in the localStorage as JSON:

```
// Set
Myarray.push(data);
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(Myarray));
```

Parse the JSON when you get the data back out (put this at the top of your script, or in your onload method):

```
// Get
if (localStorage.getItem("test")) {
    Myarray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
} else {
    // No data, start with an empty array
    Myarray = [];
}
console.log(Myarray);
```

Comment: but how do I use the same content on page reload???no one seems to be answering this?

Comment: @MESSIAH I've edited it a bit to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: I tried your code but when I click on some other link,it agains restart i.e Myarray is cleared,how can i continue with data already pushed inside myarray+data being inserted presently.??thats why we are using local storage...

Comment: I'd need to see a lot more of your code. How are you initialising Myarray? Could you post something on JSFiddle or a similar site?

Comment: well ,I just simplified my question.In my original code there is php involved and data is coming via ajax every 30 sec.I hope you understand what I am trying to explain.http://jsfiddle.net/9Tmwp/

Comment: some updates with simplification,have a look....http://jsfiddle.net/9Tmwp/1/

Comment: am i missing something here??

Comment: Replace line 3 of your file: `var pair = [];` with the get bit. You don't need the get bit just after the set bit

Comment: with what should i replace??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33498/discussion-between-rjmunro-and-messiah)

Comment: one last thing,I just closed the browser and reopened it,and that still continued.now i want to restart it only when the browser is closed,otherwise its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage works with strings only. Also, `push` returns the new length of the array, so the code you posted wont work as intended. Try this:

```
Myarray.push(data);
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(Myarray));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're storing the return value from `.push()` to local storage (which is the length of the array), instead of the actual data.

You should push to the array as required, then stringify the array and store.

```
var Myarray = [];
Myarray.push(....);

localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(Myarray);
```